# accessing F5 load balancer using unix script

Tags: shell, f5, tmsh

I'm new to F5 load balancers. Is there anyway I can stop/start servers in the F5 pool using unix scripts?

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to stop/start pool members (nodes) directly on the BIG-IP, you can use the TMSH commands within the script.  In this case:

**Force Node Offline**: `>tmsh modify /ltm node <nodename> state user-down session user-disabled` - This will prevent new connections from occuring but will not drop existing connections (will not drain)

**Delete Existing Connections**: `>tmsh delete /sys connection ss-server-addr <nodeIP>` - This will force-drain any existing connections from the node (something to do after you force offline and there are persistent connections preventing maintenance)

**Enable Node:** `>tmsh modify /ltm node <nodename> state user-up session user-enabled` - This will return the node to accepting traffic from any disabled state.

After changing a configuration you'll want to `tmsh save /sys config`.

If you want to manage these attributes remotely, you can use the iControlREST API via curl or if you want, there's a python SDK available to make use of REST commands within your py scripts.

**Curl example:** `>curl -sk -u XXXXX:XXXX https://bigp_ip_addr/mgmt/tm/ltm/node/~Common~NODE/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"state": "user-down", "session": "user-disabled"}'`

Here are the available [BIG-IP TMSH commands](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/TMSH.Commands.ashx) you can use within your script (DevCentral login required) and here is how to use the [BIG-IP iControlREST API](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControlREST.HomePage.ashx).  I use this one myself so I can run simple scripts remotely to manage common objects.  Here are the [BIG-IP iControlREST](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControlREST.APIRef_tm_ltm_node.ashx) commands specific to node management (again, DevCentral login required).

Hope this gets you where you need to be.

Comment: I'd recommend ssh instead of the rest API. Much easier to work with.